# How do I redirect a page on my website to the home page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url, redirect

I have a specific page showing up high in search engines for a specific search. However I want users to click the page and be directed to the home page of the website instead of that particular page. How would I do this? I built the site with Wordpress.

Comment: You could do a redirect over php or javascript, but then nobody would be able to read this particular page anymore, as they are always redirected to your homepage. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you redirect users away from that page, your high ranking in search engines may be short lived.

Comment: Yes it's what I want. The home page will serve them better with their search than that particular page. Please read the comment below. As for the "high ranking being short lived" - it won't. The link juice for that particular page gets transferred to the home page after I redirect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) should let you do this. Though by removing the page from being viewable, you're going to take away your users' ability to read the page that was highly relevant to their search phrase, and the page may fall out of its high ranking. So as appealing as it may be to have a high result redirect to your homepage, you probably don't actually want to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Believe it or not the homepage will serve their search better than the particular page. The search is "plumber in [location]" and the particular page has a highly keyword optimized article containing "plumber in [location]" - user's don't want to go to the site to read an article about "plumber in [location]" they want to find a plumbing company in that location - thus the redirect to the homepage that shows the name of the business, phone number, address, services, etc.

Comment: I believe a better solution would be to keep the page intact, but add something elsewhere on it that links to the relevant information, like a preamble that says something like "If you're looking to hire a plumber in [location] now, click here." That way your highly-placing page remains a highly-placing page, and your visitors can still get the information they want.